# How does a permuterm index works?

Tags: information-retrieval

I have read  [Permuterm indexes](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/permuterm-indexes-1.html)  page on stanford website, however I can't still figure out how we can reach from: `*X*` to `X*`.

So where is the `$`?

---

I can get these ones:

```
For X, look up X$
For X*, look up $X*
For *X, look up X$*
For X*Y, look up Y$X*
```

Answer (score 6):

> The idea behind Permuterm Index is to rotate wildcard query such that
>   ***** goes to the end.

Thus, you convert vague query to comparable query. As you wrote, lookup **$X*** for query **X*** because * is uncertain but the start part X is deterministic.

When it comes to *X*, we have two stars. The problem is which star should we rotate .

1. Rotate 1st star

   You regard **X*** as one part **Y**, then we get ***Y**. So we should lookup **Y$***, which is **X*$***, equivalent to **X***.
2. Rotate 2nd star

   You regard ***X** as one part **Y**, then we get **Y***. So we should lookup ***$Y**, which is ***$*X**.This is not easy to handle with.

Based on that, we can know why we lookup **X*** when we have queries like ***X***. The reason is not **$** is that **$** means the end of the word whereas our query doesn't contain information about the end.

Comment: Is it possible to query `W*X*Y*Z`? I know that `X*Y*Z` is, but I cannot come up with a solution a query for three wildcards.